# Ruby inner class of Hash

Tags: ruby, hash, inner-classes, nested-class

for example

```
class C1
     class Hash
       def ok?
          return 'nested hash ok'
       end
      end
     def m1
        return Hash.new.ok?
     end
     def m2
        return {}.ok?
     end
end
```

the C1.new.m1 works but C1.new.m2 not. what's the different meaning in naming space?

Comment: If what I want is to add method "ok?" into hash but only apply to class C1 and it's sub-class. How to make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply created a new class called `Hash`, nested inside `C1`.

You did not add a method to Ruby's `Hash` class as you were expecting.
If you wanted that, move the `class Hash` outside of `C1` and re-run: the code will perform as expected.

As your current code is, presume you named the nested class as `MyThing`. Now, you would not work `{}.ok?` to work, would you?

So to recap:

This would work:

```
class Hash
   def ok?
    return 'non-nested hash ok'
   end
end
class C1
     def m1
        return Hash.new.ok? #WORKS
     end
     def m2
        return {}.ok? #WORKS
     end
end
```

This will fail:

```
class C1
    class MyThing
      def ok?
       return 'nested hash ok'
       end
    end
     def m1
        return MyThing.new.ok? #WORKS
     end
     def m2
        return {}.ok? #FAILS
     end
end
```

Comment: You can edit the built in `Hash` class from inside `C1` by specifying the global namespace e.g. `class ::Hash`

Answer (score 0):

```
class C1
  class Hash # defines C1::Hash
    def ok?
      return 'nested hash ok'
    end
  end

  def m1
    return Hash.new.ok? # refers to C1::Hash
  end

  def m2
    return {}.ok? # refers to Hash
  end
end
```

There is no mixing of classes based on namespaces. They are separate.